# Usb drive detected but cannot be showed up anywhere in linux

Tags: linux, usb

I have about 3 USB drivers but only one of them has been behaving weird. I have a 32-GB drive which I just got it from a shop nearby, it worked fine until it stopped, I forgot why.
Here I tried `dmesg`, here is the output:

```
[16096.602902] usb 2-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=1e3d, idProduct=198a, bcdDevice= 1.00
[16096.602905] usb 2-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[16096.603283] usb-storage 2-1.5:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[16096.603722] scsi host6: usb-storage 2-1.5:1.0
[16097.644899] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ChipsBnk Flash Disk       5.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[16097.645371] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[16097.659096] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

I also typed `lsusb`, it showed me this:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0cf3:e004 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 413c:301a Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I also read this [article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26259/usb-recognized-but-not-available), I'm basically at a loss.
However, I found out that the USB appears when I tried `ls -laR /dev/disk`

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Aug 25 10:04 lvm-pv-uuid-6Jl9DO-tNo8-3Trw-vptb-VMxL-qg3o-la1VEg -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Aug 25 14:32 usb-ChipsBnk_Flash_Disk-0:0 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Aug 25 10:04 wwn-0x5000c50060859cc4 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Aug 25 10:04 wwn-0x5000c50060859cc4-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Aug 25 10:04 wwn-0x5000c50060859cc4-part2 -> ../../sda2
```

Here it appeared as sdb.

If there's anything you need to know, just ask, I can't give up on a 32-GB USB.
Thank you in advance!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, my USB was Chinese, so It wasn't good enough.
Chinese USB really sucks :(